# Javascript - Loop through sparse array and replace sparse values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through a sparse array and fill in sparse elements with a value.

`['foo', 'bar', , , ,].map(el => el || 'default')` // returns `["foo", "bar", undefined × 3]`

How would I return `["foo", "bar", "default", "default", "default", "default"]`

Comment: From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) "`map` calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results. callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; **it is not invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values**."

Comment: @pawel - Although the callback is not called for those indexes, the return value from `map()` still has those positions.

Comment: @TedHopp it does, but they're unchanged, which rather defeats the point for the OP

Comment: @TedHopp yes, because the callback hasn't been called. I'm not sure I get your point.

Comment: @pawel - The point is that `map()` won't work because OP wants the result to contain `"default"` at those positions where the original array was undefined. If your comment was simply to explain why `map()` wasn't working, that wasn't clear to me.

Comment: Is it intentional that you have 3 sparse values, but 4 `"default"` strings?

Comment: @TedHopp I know, that's why I have quoted revelant bit from the docs which explains why OP's code doesn't work :)

Comment: @Alnitak, yes, my understanding of sparse arrays is incorrect. I thought it would capture the last element after the last `,`.

Comment: If it matters, just set the array length explicitly to the desired size, rather than relying on the (slightly odd) behaviour of the array literal syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `.map` (and also `.forEach`) will skip sparse values there's no option except to use a loop, but you should explicitly check for the absence of the missing keys

```
for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
    if (!(i in a)) {       // explicit check for missing sparse value
        a[i] = "default";
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be short one `default`, but I don't think there's any way around that.

Comment: To @RickHitchcock point, it appears that all of these answers will be short one `default`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock ah, didn't spot the OP has one more `default` than element entries - perhaps that was a mistake?

Comment: He may think that the last comma creates a new undefined element, which would not be the case.

Comment: @RickHitchcock, yes, that is my thought. I'm new to sparse arrays, and I take it that is not the case?

Comment: Correct.  If an array ends with a comma, the final comma is ignored.  See https://jsfiddle.net/mm5utmwh/ for a simple example.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
function Fill(n, _default) {
  return Array.apply(null,n).map(function(val) {
    return val || _default;
  });
}
var newa = Fill(myarray, "default");
console.log(JSON.stringify(newa));
```

Shown working here:

```js
var myarray = ['foo', , 'bar', , , , ];
function Fill(n, _default) {
  return Array.apply(null, n).map(function(val) {
    console.log("val:" + val);
    return val || _default;
  });
}
var newa = Fill(myarray, "default");
console.log(JSON.stringify(newa));
```

Comment: @Alnitak Are you sure? Try `Array.apply( null, [, , ,]).map( i => typeof i )`, should return `[ "undefined", "undefined", "undefined" ]`.

Comment: ok, this works, but it's kinda kludgy, since it replaces the implicit `undefined` sparse entries with explicit `undefined` entries, and _then_ replaces any falsey value found.

Comment: @pawel I deleted that comment when I realised my test was wrong

Comment: The "falsey" value can be modified in the return statement as needed; but this does use the map :) however ugly

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss it does, but it doesn't permit (should it matter) any distinction between a truly missing (sparse) value and an existing value of `undefined`.

Comment: Nice and neat solution!